# How to do Islamic Conquest in This Postmodern Era

Tags: practical-islam

God has approved the Muslims to do Conquest not for worldly gain but to make the area that is not submit to the Authority of God become submissive to His Authority. Imagine if the conquest of Europe and US is successful, there will be much much less drug industry, obscene movies/music industry, less white supremacist, and most importantly the world economic system will not be backed by riba anymore, and certainly other wisdoms as well. So what is the practical steps to do the Conquest in this era (preparations, rules, etc)?

Comment: This doesn't look like a subjective question. Please check our [help] to learn what is on-topic and what we regard as a constructive question.

Comment: @Hassanal Shah - As per Islam, defending Muslims currently being oppressed takes priority over initiating new conquests.. otherwise you will be biting off more than you can chew. So first Muslims need to unite and deal with those issues first.

Answer (score 1):

Conquest can be done but first we need an Islamic State (Khilafah). It is that simple. And we need to understand what conquest really means... The concept of Conquest in Islam is quite different from Western one... The West view conquest as overbearing dominance, whereas Islam sees it as removing the physical obstacles preventing the spread of Islam to other lands. Hence, we see that [British](https://www.islamiqate.com/3416/was-britain-a-force-for-good-in-the-world) and [American](https://www.islamiqate.com/3399/is-america-a-force-for-good-in-the-world) dominance did not bring good to the world, but [Islam's](https://www.islamiqate.com/4001/was-islam-historically-a-force-for-good) did.

Comment: alhamdulilah this the correct answer and an excellent one.

Comment: Ok we need to create Khilafah

Comment: Khilafah is not created, my brother rather established but I assume that is what you mean. Indeed, we need to establish Khilafah because all classical islamic scholars have agreed unanimously on its obligation. Read scholars views and statements https://www.islamiqate.com/3694/how-did-the-classical-scholars-define-the-term-khilafah